# How to apply ng-if for text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

[Plunker.](https://jsfiddle.net/bdmqxr5y/732/)

In my plunker I have two text boxes.there I have applied `ng-if` to the text box.If the ng-model contains `-1` value then it need to leave that text box and able to enter another value, if it is other than `-1` then there is no issues.Just we can continue.

But here if I apply `ng-if` then it is hiding the text box, but I don't want to hide,Just I want to hide the value.

**HTML:-**

```
<input type="text" ng-if ="model !=-1"  ng-model="model"/>
```

**js:-**

```
  $scope.model = '-1';
  $scope.model1 = '1';
```

Comment: sorry, I have edited that question

Answer (score 1):

Actually `ng-if` directive hides its parent when it is true. I think you actually is to change the value of the text box when someone enters -1. So use `$watch`.

```
var module = angular.module("myModule", []);

module.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.model = '-1';
$scope.model1 = '1';
$scope.txtValue = 1;
$scope.$watch("txtValue", function (newVal) {
    if (newVal == '-1')
    {
        $scope.model1 = -1;
        $scope.txtValue = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.model1 = newVal;
    }        
    });
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="txtValue"/>
</div>
</div>
```

And remember to remove `ng-if` directive

Comment: it should not  be zero again, it should contain `-1` only and it need to hide the value

Comment: I edited the answer. can you check it out now. Put `txtValue` to textBox's `ng-model`

Comment: could you please give me html sample code for the above js code as I confused

Comment: I added html part for the script. check it out

Answer (score 0):

You can add another input which will be visible when ng-model contains -1 and null the value so user can enter new value.

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text" ng-if ="model !=-1"  ng-model="model"/>
    <input type="text" ng-if ="model1 !=-1"  ng-model="model1"/>
    <input type="text" ng-show="model ==-1" ng-model="model = null" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems okay, but the ng-model should contain the -1 only

Comment: Just store original value and if input won't be touched (value = null) replace model with original value ...